Problem reading data from a web service with Genexus
I'm trying to receive data from a web service. It works in Postman. The only thing I did was set username and password as params and I received a json as response

But when I try to do the same thing in Genexus...

I get this response

The same one I have if I don't pass the user and password parameters into postman. I've tried using other methods instead of AddVariable, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

I found the solution: the data should not be passed to it via AddVariable, but via parameters in the URL, like this

